# How to extend class?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I'm making a change to an API that serves data. Some of the searches require data about an author and take a `IAuthor` object. The API has an `IAuthor` interface and a single concrete class that implements `IAuthor` called `Author`.

I need to add a boolean property, `IsNovelist` that will change the semantics of some but not all searches.

I've heard about the [open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and it would seem that changing the `IAuthor` and/or `Author` classes would violate this. How then to make this simple change?

---

UPDATE:

Perhaps I was concentrating on the wrong class. I don't want to add *behaviour* to `Author` class (it's just a way of passing parameters to the API). So a `Decorated` author wouldn't need a boolean flag because it would be `isNovelist == true` by implication.

I need to change the behaviour of the `GetBooks` method given an author who is flagged as being a novelist. So something more like this but my thinking is probably wonky because now I'm changing (not extending) the `Books` class:

```
//Before
class Books 
{
   public Books[] GetBooks(IAuthor author){
       // Call data access GetBooks...
    }
}


//After
class Books 
{
   public Books[] GetBooks(IAuthor author){
       // To maintain pre-existing behaviour
       // call data access GetBooks with SQL param @isNovelist = false...
       // (or don't pass anything because the SQL param defaults to false)
    }

   public Books[] GetBooksForNovelist(IAuthor author){
       // To get new behaviour
       // call data access GetBooks with SQL param @isNovelist = true
    }
}
```

Comment: One option is to create a new class `Novelist` that inherits from `Author`

Comment: The Decorator Pattern can also be used to resolve such issues.http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx

Comment: How about creating a enum to hold the type of Author?

Comment: I started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375378/extend-not-change-search-class-for-new-behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 2 :

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IAuthor author = new Novelist();
        author.Name = "Raj";

        // i guess u have check if author is a novelist
        // the simple way is by safe typecasting

        Novelist novelist = author as Novelist;

        if (novelist != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wohoo, i am a novelist");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Damn,i cant write novel");
        }


    }
```

Solution 1 :

```
public enum AuthourType
{
    Novelist,
    Other
}

public interface IAuthor
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    AuthourType Type { get; set; }

}

public class  Novelist : IAuthor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AuthourType Type { get; set; }
    // incase u dont want it to be set to other value
    /*        
    public AuthourType Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set
        {
            if (value != AuthourType.Novelist)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Type");
            }
            type = value;
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: @acrilige - check the solution 2

Comment: @acrilige - u can even have strict property setter


        public AuthourType Type
        {
            get { return type; }
            set
            {
                if (value != AuthourType.Novelist)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Type");
                }
                type = value;
            }
        }

Comment: I think that point to author's style both with enum and separate class is not very correct. Better to use OR enum OR separate class for this...

Comment: @acrilige - depends on the coder , type-casting would have been fine for me!

Comment: I started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375378/extend-not-change-search-class-for-new-behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do using the decorator pattern

```
interface IAuthor
{
    void someMethod();
}

class Author:IAuthor{

    public void someMethod(){
        //Implementation here
    }
}

//Class that will add the extra behavior.
class DecoratedAuthor : IAuthor
{
    IAuthor author;
    public bool isNovelist{get;set;}//Add the extra Behavior

    public DecoratedAuthor(IAuthor auth)
    {
        this.author = auth;
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        //Call the Author's version here
        author.someMethod();

        //check if he is a novelist
        isNovelist = true;
    }

}


public class program{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAuthor auth = new Author();
        DecoratedAuthor novAuth = new DecoratedAuthor(auth);

        DecoratedAuthor.someMethod();
        //see if he is a novelist
        Console.WriteLine(novAuth.isNovelist);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean and on reflection I think I need to extend another class instead e.g. the class with the `GetGBooksByAuthor` method. See update to the question.

Comment: I started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375378/extend-not-change-search-class-for-new-behaviour).